# how to get a third variable using a doubled join variable in php

Tags: php

PHP CODE:

```
$video1="welcome.mp4";
$video2="movie.mp4";
$video3="ends.mp4";

$num_id="1";
$get = '$' . "video" . $num_id; 
$file = $get;
echo "<a href=Player.php?file=$file'>Play</a>";
```

html code results:

```
<a href="player.php?file=$video1">Play</a>
```

HTML - expectancy:

```
<a href="player.php?file=welcome.mp4">Play</a>
```

Comment: Whats a `doubled join variable`?  What you get is exactly what I would expect to get given the code in the question.

Comment: It would seem to be much simpler for you to use arrays

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this.

```
$videos = ['welcome.mp4','movie.mp4','ends.mp4'];

foreach($videos as $video){
  echo "<a href=Player.php?file=$video'>Play</a><br>";
}
```

Comment: I agree, using an array would be much better than distinct variables. Might want to add an example of getting a specific one like they're trying to do in the question, though.

Comment: thank you very much. its works, but i have more one solution
Your code is OK
and it too: echo "<a href=Player.php?file=${$video}'>Play</a><br>";

Answer (score 0):

I would do this (If I wanted to be Kool, or confuse a junior developer .. lol )

```
$video1="welcome.mp4";
$video2="movie.mp4";
$video3="ends.mp4";

$num_id="1";
$get = ${"video".$num_id}; 
$file = $get;
echo "<a href=Player.php?file=$file'>Play</a>";
```

Output

```
<a href=Player.php?file=welcome.mp4'>Play</a>
```

But I am not sure you are ready to have access to that much power...

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f7b9380d322af93d6e8463932c1c3bf8650c7d35)